# What are those folders in SDL-1.2.15

Tags: sdl

I'm trying to understand source code of SDL-1.2.15, and to find out how it renders stuff on windows. But I can't find where the rendering is happening. I looked inside `SDL-1.2.15/src/video` folder, and there is a ton of subfolders, and I don't know what any of these stands for. See for yourself.

```
aalib/        directfb/  ipod/       os2fslib/  quartz/     windib/
ataricommon/  dummy/     maccommon/  photon/    riscos/     windx5/
bwindow/      fbcon/     macdsp/     picogui/   svga/       wscons/
caca/         gapi/      macrom/     ps2gs/     symbian/    x11/
dc/           gem/       nanox/      ps3/       vgl/        xbios/
dga/          ggi/       nds/        qtopia/    wincommon/  Xext/
```

Is this documented somewhere? This is a pretty popular library, so it probably is documented, right? Right? What's the point of having source code if you can't even understand it, if you can't find functions you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not all the names are self-explanatory, they contain some hints.
directfb, fbcon (framebuffer console) and X (x11, Xext) are output layers on Linux (unix).

The ones starting with ***win*** indicate they are for Windows. More specifically, windib should be about device independent bitmaps (DIBs), dx5 about DirectX 5, and wincommon about some common stuff. Indeed, using **grep** shows that (only) these folders contain Windows-specific code:

```
grep -r windows.h src/video/*
[ lists files in the win* folders ]
```

You could also just compile the package on Windows and see which files were compiled (which folders contain object files)

However, to find out what it actually does, you should rather study the function you're interested in (e.g. SDL_BlitSurface), look at it's implementation, and then look at the implementation of the functions it uses. Start in SDL_video.h (and notice that SDL_BlitSurface is just a define).

You should use some tool to search the code base. Grep or some IDE. Or both.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why not SDL2?

These are different SDL's video drivers. You can get what driver is used by your program by calling [SDL_VideoDriverName](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_VideoDriverName). Which driver will be used determined by target platform (e.g. operating system - most drivers are platform-specific), environment variable `SDL_VIDEODRIVER`, or calling side.

Comment: Well, because I suspect that they throw away pure GDI rendering in favour of modern 3d stuff, and I'm looking for the simpliest api. I want my exe as small as possible. Thanks for info!

Comment: @ViktorMelly I don't know about SDL 2, but at least in 1.2 there was always a GDI fallback if DirectX was not available. However, in this case, don't study the code so much. Rather study the output of ***./configure --help*** (or open the configure script in an editor, about line 1500). There is actually a list of all the parts you can enable and disable, even explaining what some of the subfolders actually mean. You'll probably be interested in ***--disable-directx***.

Comment: @DanielS Can you give me a hint on how to compile it on windows? I tried to compile SDL2.0.3 in VS2010, with no success. https://forums.libsdl.org/viewtopic.php?t=11423

Comment: No, sorry, I never did that.